# OpenID Connect with ASP NET Core 3.1 without well-known URL

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid

I'm trying to configure OpenID Connect with ASP.NET Core 3.1 in this way:

```
 .AddOpenIdConnect(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.Authority = "https://myurl.io";
                    cfg.ClientId = "123455555";
                    cfg.ClientSecret = "11111";
                    cfg.ResponseType = "code";
                    cfg.Scope.Clear();
                    cfg.Scope.Add("openid");
                });
```

But when I try to startup the application I got the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.

Well, I know this is because I don't have a well-known medadata url, is there a way to ignore this url and fill in the information manually in `Startup.cs` ?

Comment: _" I don't have a well-known medadata url"_ Does the OIDC provider not support discovery?

Comment: @abdusco github for example has no discovery for OIDC (as far as I know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the configuration directly:

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
        options.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
        {
            JwksUri = "",
            AuthorizationEndpoint = "",
            TokenEndpoint = "",
            UserInfoEndpoint = "",
            Issuer = "",
            // ...
        };
    })
```

Depending on your needs, you probably need to fill at least:

- authorization endpoint
- token endpoint
- userinfo endpoint
- issuer
- jwks endpoint (or perform validation differently)